# Oracle Apex Print Setting

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to the Oracle Apex, Created a desktop application when trying to print the values are getting displayed in a new row, the issue only in portrait Layout. Kindly guide to solve the issue.

Attaching the screen shot for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is, but you can manipulate the output using CSS media queries http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/07/apex-printer-friendly-pages-with-css-media-queries.html

Comment: Or use something like Apache FOP.